# Which is the best option to create vector images using php?

Tags: php, gd, vector-graphics, imagick

I am planning to make an online sticker design site for a company.That is the users can login to the site and enter the text for the sticker then change the font,color,shadow,outline color.

I am using PHP's GD library for creating images.
I am also using php's Imagick plugin to apply some text warp to the image.

But the problem I am facing is what the images created from this method are low quality images.

**I want to make such site like this:-
http://www.speedysigns.com/tool/lt/index/index/product_id/31990/**

I think that images created from this are vector images.

I tried **Imagick** to create vector images.But I can't find a better tutorial to create vector images using Imagick.

So can you please suggest which library I may use to create such high quality images.
Otherwise suggest a good tutorial to use Imagick to create vector images.

Thanks friends.
 By Sukesh B R

Comment: Possible dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620574/creating-vector-graphics-with-php

Comment: But this is thread does not give me a solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Cairo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.cairo.php) does what you're interested in, and more.

> The Cairo Graphics Library takes a vector approach to graphics, allowing smaller size, infinite zooming, and moving, scaling and rotating without degrading image quality.

Comment: Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams,  can we create vector graphics with imagic?

Comment: Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, Thank you for your quick response. I can see that Cairo is poorly documented. Somebody already tried using the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620574/creating-vector-graphics-with-php. Could you please provide some sample script that uses cairo. Just to draw shadow to a text is enough. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the link you have shared does not work on vector images.There are all vector images.But if you want to use vector images then you have to use [Inkscape.org](http://inkscape.org)